# Is their any drawback to have a pool of exoplayer in memory?

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have an app with show to user a feed of photos/video similar to what is Instagram. I want the smoothest scrolling experience as possible (avoid any lags in the scroll). Problem is that creating an empty simpleExoPlayer can take around **10 to 20ms** (so enough to have a frame drop in the scroll). So I want to create at the starting time of the app let's say a **pool of 10 empty simpleExoPlayer** and gave them to the feed when it's will request. I will recreate or reset the used simpleExoPlayer when the app is not scrolling (this why i need min 10 because i need to wait the user stop to scroll).

Is their any drawback to have 10 empty exoplayer in memory? i mean does exoplayer, even empty, will use lot of resources/memories/CPU ?

Also what the tips can i follow to have the the smoothest scrolling experience as possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's primarily not about memory but about the Codec instances which are limited on the device and you share with other apps.

Each instance of ExoPlayer for video playback is usually setup with a MediaCodecVideoAudioRenderer and MediaCodecAudioRenderer. The Codec instance is usually based on a hardware codec and the number of hardware instances available on a device is both, limited and hard to figure out. It's not trivial to know how many Codec instances are available at any given time.

So if you create too many ExoPlayers you will get an exception because there are not enough codecs available. You can workaround this a little by using a software codec, but for video this is something which I'd not recommend because it's not likely to perform well.

So, given you can figure out how many instances are available on a given device, you can create as many players as codecs are available. I'm unclear how that could be done reliably though (except with ugly hacks).

In general I'd recommend a single player only.

If you want to know about the memory consumption you might want to measure this on your device, which seems not too difficult.

Comment: thanks marc! But if i do not create the MediaSource but only the simpleExoPlayer (so without preparing it) does it's still use a MediaCodecVideoAudioRenderer and MediaCodecAudioRenderer?

Comment: Check when the renderers are created.

Comment: seam they are created when the simpleExoPlayer is created :(